# Angular 2 lifecycle hooks not executing, constructor also

Tags: angular, routes, lifecycle

I am trying to call a service inside ngOnInit method. Anyway any of lifecycle methods or constructor are not being called. So i guess component is not constructed. But how ? Pages are rendered i have Home module inside MainFrameModule rendered:
[image]

Here is application module diagram
[image]

**I am trying to call them inside MainFrameComponent and/or Home component. In both cases nothing.**

And here is MainFrameModule routing

```
export const mainFrameRoutes:Routes = [
  { path: 'main-frame', component : MainFrameComponent,
      children : [
       { path:'', redirectTo : '/main-frame/home',pathMatch:'full'}
      ,{ path:'home', component : HomeComponent}
      ,{ path: 'products',component:ProductsComponent,loadChildren :'app/components/products/products.module#ProductsModule'}
      ,{ path:'account', loadChildren : 'app/components/account/account.module#AccountModule'}
      ,{ path:'billing',component:BillingComponent, loadChildren : 'app/components/billing/billing.module#BillingModule'}
      ,{ path:'affiliate',component: AffiliateComponent, loadChildren : 'app/components/affiliate/affiliate.module#AffiliateModule'} 
      ]
  }
];
```

MainFrameComponent:

```
import { Component,HostBinding,Input,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../entities/user';
import { LimeProxiesService } from '../../services/limeproxies.service';


@Component({
    selector : 'main-frame',
    templateUrl : 'app/templates/main-frame/main-frame.template.html'
})

export class MainFrameComponent implements OnInit {

    @HostBinding('class') mainFrameClass = 'page page--one-col';
    @Input() user:User;
    private errorMessage;

    constructor(private limeProxiesService:LimeProxiesService){
        console.log("in constructor");
    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        console.log("ngOnChanges called");
    }


    ngAfterContentInit(){
        console.log("ngAfterContentInit called");
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit called");
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("ngOnDestroy called");
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("ngOnInit called");
      this.setUser();
    }

    setUser(){
        this.limeProxiesService.getUserProfile()
                                             .subscribe(
                                    //success
                                    user => this.user = user,
                                    //error
                                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
                                    //completed
                                    );
    }


}
```

Or HomeComponent:

```
import { Component,HostBinding,OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeSidebarComponent } from './home-sidebar.component';
import { HomeMainContentComponent } from './home-main-content.component';
import { User } from '../../entities/user';
import { LimeProxiesService } from '../../services/limeproxies.service';

@Component({
    selector: '.home-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/home/home.template.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

     @HostBinding('class') homeClass = 'page__content-inner';

      @Input() user:User;
    private errorMessage;

    constructor(private limeProxiesService:LimeProxiesService){
    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        console.log("ngOnChanges called");
    }


    ngAfterContentInit(){
        console.log("ngAfterContentInit called");
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit called");
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("ngOnDestroy called");
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("ngOnInit called");
      this.setUser();
    }

    setUser(){
        this.limeProxiesService.getUserProfile()
                                             .subscribe(
                                    //success
                                    user => this.user = user,
                                    //error
                                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
                                    //completed
                                    );
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Lifecycle methods are called on localhost, but not on apache server remotely.
[image]

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue

Comment: The same here using webpack to bundle